# How to the @ symbol in RediSearch?

Tags: json, redis, redisearch, redisjson

I'm using the modules RedisJSON and RediSearch together to perform search queries on JSON data.
Given a json list like this:

> {"email": "test1@example.com", "is_checked": 1}

I do:

```
FT.CREATE myidx ON JSON SCHEMA $.email AS email TAG
FT.SEARCH myidx "@email:'test1@example.com'"
```

but I got `Syntax error`

How can I select with the value "test1@example.com"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape special characters, like @, with a backslash:

```
FT.SEARCH myidx "@email:'test1\@example.com'"
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Full details on when to use escaping here: https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/Escaping/

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue and the accepted answer didn't work for me, but I found a solution in [this RediSearch issue](https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch/issues/2019).

With an index where there's an email field stored as a `TAG` you can do a search like this:

```
FT.SEARCH myidx "@email:{ test1\\@example\\.com }"
```

With the `@` and `.` characters escaped.

Here are the docs for querying on `TAG` fields as well: https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/reference/tags/#querying-tag-fields

Comment: This is the correct answer, as it prevents the tokenization of the value on the '.' and properly uses the '}' since the field is defined as a TAG.